# sybase command to find out the duplicate value in a coulmn in sybase

Tags: sybase

I have a table named tarty which consistss of variious filels

```
CREATE TABLE tarty  ( 
    aer_id      int NOT NULL,
    iewtwr      int NOT NULL,
    )
```

Can you please advise what will be the sybase command as i want to check that
aer_id should not have the same value

that is i want that if aer_id have the dame value in the table then it should be get listed out please
advise the sybase command for that

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing Sybase-specific about the following query, this is standard SQL:

```
select aer_id, count(*) as nr_of_times 
from tarty
group by aer_id
having count(*) > 1
```

If you want to guarantee uniqueness, declare the column as 'unique' so that a constraint will apply.